# Recursive euclid algorithm for gcd complexity

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

I am trying to calculate the complexity of the euclidean algorithm for finding the greatest common divisor (gcd) (recursive version).

Here's the pseudo code:

```
algorithm euclid(a,b)
if b = 0 then
    return a
else
    return euclid(b, a mod b)
end if
```

My initial thought is that every time the recursive function is called, its complexity is O(1). I also know that $b\ge F_k$ for k calls of the function, as I have proven this by induction previously (see proof below). This means that the runtime grows with the input b and this is where I am stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Additional Question:** Does calculating the complexity of the recursive algorithm work in any way similar to the calculation of the complexity of the iterative algorithm in this post: [Euclid's Algorithm Time Complexity](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/72200/euclids-algorithm-time-complexity)? What would be similarities and differences?

**Proof by induction**, that $a\ge F_{k+1}$ and $b \ge F_k$ iff $a>b\ge 0$ for $k \ge 1$ recursive calls of the function:

1. Let $n_0=1$ then a%b = 0 and gcd(a,b) = b. From this follows that $F_1 = 1 \le b$, since if $b<1$, $k$ would have to be $k = 0$. $F_2 = 1 \le a$ is also valid, since otherwise $a>b$ would be invalid.
2. $a\ge F_{n+1}$and$b\ge F_n$, $k = n$,  is valid.
3. To show: For $k=n+1$: $a \ge F_{n+2}$ and $b\ge F_{n+1}$

   Let *euclid*$(a_{n+1},b_{n+1})$ be a call of the recursive function
   above.

   Then for $q \in N, q>0$: 
   $b_n+1 = a_n \ge F_{n+1}$

and

$$a_{n+1} = b_{n+1}*q+b_n
= a_n*q+b_n \ge F_{n+1}*q+F_n \ge F_{n+1}+F_n 
= F_n+2$$
Q.E.D

Comment: Many algorithms textbooks have an analysis of the running time of the Euclidean algorithm.  I suggest you check some of them out; you should be able to find a good explanation.

Comment: Can you recommend any textbook in particular? Right now I have "Introduction to Algorithms" by Cormen, but I am still quite lost. Could be I am not doing it right though...

Comment: If a ≥ b, then you can either prove easily how the product ab changes in one step, or how the larger of a and b changes in two iterations.